# Временная таблица. при переходе на другую страницу не работает

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii, temporary-table

Используем временную таблицу для хранения временных данных.
На странице, где мы создаем временную таблицу, там все работает,а при переходе на другую страницу сайта PHP выдает ошибку:
"Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.tmp_hotels' doesn't exist".

Код:

```
    $temp = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_hotels LIKE hotels')->execute();

    Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('tmp_hotels', ['search_key', 'book_allowed', 'name', 'address', 'category', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'image', 'type', 'classifications', 'services', 'rooms', 'distance', 'min_price'], $ins)->execute();

    $hotels = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tmp_hotels');
    $this->dump($posts);
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Для разработки используем Yii2, PHP7, MySQL 5.6

Comment: Скоп временной таблицы - соединение. Смена соединения (чему пул соединений очень способствует) или реконнект - и нет твоей темповой таблицы, она осталась "где-то там".

Comment: что нужно сделать чтобы временная таблица не удалялось?

Comment: Жёстко работать в рамках одного соединения. Не меняя и не переоткрывая его.

Comment: Еще можно не использовать временную таблицу для хранения данных.